# read input from keyboard in R

Tags: r

I know this is very basic question as I am new to R I have this question.

How to allow users to enter numbers from the keyboard.
Provide users to enter how many numbers they want to enter from key board and according to that provide facility to enter numbers.

eg:

```
How many numbers you want to enter?  
> 10  
Enter numbers:  
> 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

Comment: hello check `?readline`

Comment: I second @s.brunel 's comment, have a look at the [documentation about readline](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readline.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
   while(T) {
    num <- readline("How many number do you want to enter? > ")
    num <- as.numeric(num)
    if (!is.na(num)) {
      num2 <- readline(paste0("Enter ",num, " numbers > "))
      print(num2)
      break
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @raistlin..But it doesn't provide validation of numbers..consider users provide input as 5 for the first question but it allows users to enter more than 5 numbers for the above code or less than 5 numbers

Comment: Perhaps the problem was that you were not clear about your expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function that will asks the users How many numbers they want to enter and based on that count it provides facility to enter the integers

```
readnumber <- function()
{ 
    n <- readline(prompt="How many numbers do you want to enter: ")
    n <- as.integer(n)
    if (is.na(n)){
        n <- readnumber()
    }
    Numbers<-c()
    for (i in 1:n){
        num <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
        Numbers[i]<-as.numeric(num)
    }
    return(Numbers)    
}
print(readnumber())
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already anwered, `readline` is the function that answers your question. About your example, here's an attempt to reproduce the requested behavior.

```
N <- as.numeric(readline("How many number do you want to enter? "))
x <- vector()  # making sure x is empty

for (n in seq_len(N)) {
    new_x <- readline(paste0("Enter number ", n, " of ", N, ": "))
    x <- append(x, as.numeric(new_x))
}

cat("Here are the entered numbers:\n")
print(x)
```